# How to find latest angular-ci release that uses webpack?

Tags: angular-cli

As of September 1, 2016, the latest release is `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8`. I found out about this by doing `npm install -g angular-cli@webpack`. Is there a way to find out what the latest version is before actually installing? like a dry-run?

And on the angular-cli github (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), where is the source for `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8`? All I see in the releases page is `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases. Where is the `webpack.8` at?

thanks.

Comment: Working on getting that tagged, it should've been tagged at the time of release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list versions of an npm package by running

`npm show angular-cli versions`

You can also list the tags of an npm package by running

`npm show angular-cli dist-tags`

I will also update the tags so the release tab in Github shows the new version properly.